# How to use Python Package django-getenv?

Tags: python

I would like to set environment variables for my Python application. I have looked at this package "[django-getenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-getenv) 1.3.1" But I''m a little confused.

> If you’re using django-dotenv to get the most out of your .env file

Do I have to use this with another package? I wanted to have 2 different environments. I don;t see how setting one .env file detects different environments.

I was thinking of having to files statging, prod when somehow it uses on or the other. How can I do this?

Comment: Hey @OrbiterFleet, did you figure it out eventually? :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to use it with the `dotenv` package, but it might be convenient if you plan to use Heroku or if you want a simple way to store your configuration in a file.

The [`getenv`](https://github.com/schwuk/django-getenv) module [simply wraps](https://github.com/schwuk/django-getenv/blob/master/getenv/env.py) [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) to get Python values from your environment, since normally you only get strings.

The `.env` file is used by [foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/) to read an environment from a file. If you start your Django-project without using foreman, however, this file will not be read by default. Instead you can use the [`dotenv`](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv) module to import the `.env` file into your environment.

It's not enough to just import the `dotenv` module, you also have to initialize it by calling `dotenv.read_dotenv()`. This will [set the default value](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv/blob/1f96f1784b2ead331f18fa6c27b8533828ac0b89/dotenv.py#L51) of environment variables, meaning that if you have a variable `X` in both the `.env` file and in your environment - the environment variable will take precedence.

To make Django's `manage.py` file use the `.env` file, add these lines to it:

```
import dotenv
dotenv.read_dotenv()
```

Here's an example of how this might work. The script `printfoo.py` uses `getenv` to read and print the environment variable `FOO`:

**printfoo.py:**

```
import getenv
import dotenv

dotenv.read_dotenv()

print "FOO=%s" % getenv.env('FOO')
```

Here's what happens if you try this in a shell:

```
$ echo "FOO=bar" > .env
$ python printfoo.py 
FOO=bar
$ export FOO='hi'
$ python printfoo.py 
FOO=hi
$ unset FOO
$ python printfoo.py 
FOO=bar
$ echo "FOO=bye" > .env
$ python printfoo.py 
FOO=bye
```